# "Gait" as a verb. Is it common?

Tags: word-usage

[Oxford Dictionary online (ODO)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gait) doesn't have a definition for the verb but a few other dictionaries have it. Should I use it as a verb? Is it common nowadays to use it as verb?

Comment: You could've tried to run a Google Books search, or a Google Ngram search, say, for "gaited" (past tense form) or "gaiting". That would've given you an approximate picture of how widely it is/was used. An example from a 2009 book: "As the girls and I catapulted into show careers, I began to realize not all my Tennessee Walking Horses **gaited** the same way." So I guess the word is in use, although its use is limited by some particular niches.

Comment: The online OED has two entries for the verb *gait*. Please be more specific.

Comment: @CopperKettle Thanks. It seems it's not common. Would you please tell me if you would use this word in daily conversation?

Comment: If I were a horsekeeper or horse enthusiast in some English-speaking country, I would gladly use it in daily conversation. Should I use it in daily conversation in Yekaterinburg, Russia, I'm afraid people would be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary.com gives this:

> verb (used with object)
>
> 3. to teach a specified gait or gaits to (a horse).

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gait?s=t

Also see: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gait

> transitive verb
>
> 1. to train (a horse or a dog) to use a particular gait or set of gaits
> 2. to lead (a show dog) before a judge to display carriage and movement
>
> intransitive verb
>
> to walk with a particular gait
>
> Examples of GAIT
>
> Patricia Craige, who has guided Norwegian elkhounds to the final at Westminster eight times, gaited Ch. Vin-Melca's Bombardier to breed honors. —Walter R. Fletcher, New York Times,13 Feb. 1991
>
> As he watched the flashy dogs gaiting in the rings, he knew in his heart that he wanted to show dogs. Seeing the different breeds was thrilling. —Jacqueline Fraser, Dog Fancy, Sept. 1991

You don't use the verb on humans, mostly horses and dogs.

I haven't run into it being used as a verb until today, though. The two examples were before the turn of the century. It seems **uncommon**.

Answer (score 0):

Any noun can be turned into a verb. It's a matter of context, as well as taste. It is not advisable to turn nouns into verbs indiscriminately. You won't gain much respect from polite society by using "impact" and "interface" as verbs. They'll think you have no taste. Deplorably, they will be right.

That said, "gait" as a verb does apply - to horses. Teaching a horse how to walk a certain way is "gaiting" it, as attested to by the dictionary:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gait?s=t

**gait**

to teach a specified gait or gaits to (a horse).